# What version of OpenSSL is needed to sign with sha256WithRSAEncryption

Tags: php, cryptography, openssl

Using PHP 5.2.4 and the OpenSSL 0.9.8g module I am trying to create a signed digest

```
openssl_sign($stuff, $signeddigest, $key, 'sha256WithRSAEncryption');
```

Alas $signeddigest is returned empty and I get no errors.

If don't specify the 'sha256WithRSAEncryption' algorithm a signed digest is returned by using the default algorithm.

The same code is running fine on PHP 5.3.10 and OpenSSL 1.0.0g. Is the 'sha256WithRSAEncryption' algorithm not supported in OpenSSL 0.9.8g?

Comment: Could you see what `openssl_get_md_methods` returns? Could you try an integer constant instead of the `'sha256WithRSAEncryption'` string? It seems the API suddenly accepted strings for some reasons too, which does not seem documented in the API...

Comment: openssl_get_md_methods() comes back as undefined. If I try to use an integer constant only 1 through 4 relates to implemented algorithms - I would have expected that 'sha256WithRSAEncryption' was tied to index 47.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good friend came up with a workaround for using sha256WithRSAEncryption on an old PHP 5.2.4 and OpenSSL 0.9.8g module.

Using the information available at http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html he wrote me the following snippet:

```
function my_openssl_sign($data, &$signature, $priv_key_id, $signature_alg = 'sha256WithRSAEncryption') {
    $pinfo = openssl_pkey_get_details($priv_key_id);
    $hash = hash('sha256', $data);
    $t = '3031300d060960864801650304020105000420'; # sha256
    $t .= $hash;
    $pslen = $pinfo['bits']/8 - (strlen($t)/2 + 3);

    $eb = '0001' . str_repeat('FF', $pslen) . '00' . $t;
    $eb = pack('H*', $eb);

    return openssl_private_encrypt($eb, $signature, $priv_key_id, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING); 
}
```

Thank you, Mads, you're made of awesomeness!

Comment: Wow, great solution. Do you also have a similar solution for openssl_ verify

Comment: No, we had an more current setup on that side of the system.

Comment: Actually I found it online: https://code.google.com/p/nemid-php/source/browse/trunk/lib/Nemid.php

look at the Nemid52Compat class

this is also writen by Mads

Comment: In case you're wondering where that SHA256 magic constant comes from, it's from [RFC3447](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/signature_8c-source.html#l01273)

Comment: thanks so much for this... this saved the day for a project on an older app.